# Angular Router navigate with relativeTo activated route missing a path level

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an Angular Routing with this configuration

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'clients',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: <sample-component>,
        canActivate: [<sample-guard>],
      },
      {
        path: ':clientId',
        canActivate: [<sample-guard>],
        loadChildren: () => import('./client.route')
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'impl/:implId/create',
    component: <sample-component>,
    canActivate: [<sample-guard>],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: <some-other-child>,
        pathMatch: "full"
      },
      {
         // Some other child
      },
      {
        path: 'preview',
        loadChildren: () => import('./preview.route'),
        canActivate: [<sample-guard>]
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

Now, I have a reusable component that's being shared on `/preview` and `/:clientId` paths. This is the routing configuration those routings:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
    {

        path: '',
        component: <sample-component, this is the only difference I have for those routing configurations>,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'shared/:sharedId',
                loadComponent: () => import('../../components/shared.component').then(s => s.SharedComponent)
            }
        ]
    }
];

export default routes;
```

In the component with `empty path`, I'm reusing a component that has a default redirect to `shared/:sharedId` path. This is the redirect function:

```
  goToDefaultFlow(shared: Shared): void {
    console.log(this.router.url)
    this.router.navigate(['shared', shared.id], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

For the `:clientId` path, this is working, I was able to get the proper `relativeTo` path and was able to redirect. However, for `preview`, I am missing one level, instead of being redirected to `impl/:implId/create/preview/shared/:sharedId`, the application is being redirected to `impl/:implId/create/shared/:sharedId`.

I tried to change the `relativeTo` to `this.route.parent`, but still no luck.

Comment: PS: Looking at the `console.log `of `this.router.url`, the output is `impl/:implId/create/preview/shared`,

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I added a workaround for this issue.

In the component with `empty path`, I've added

```
currentUrl = computed<string>(() => `/${this.router.url}`);
```

And modified the navigate function:

```
goToDefaultFlow(shared: Shared): void {
  this.router.navigate([this.currentUrl(), 'shared', shared.id]);
}
```

I'm still waiting for the proper and cleaner solution to this.

Comment: This isn't the best workaround, it is very fragile and needs hacky solution to maintain other cases.